NextJS doesn't load module's CSS file on Vercel but does on local development machine
I am using React Day picker calendar module and loading styles according to their docs:

If you are using a React framework, such as Next.js or Gatsby, or a
bundler like Webpack with css-loader, import the CSS file in your
app's main JavaScript or TypeScript file:

./App.jsx
import "react-day-picker/style.css";

Thats exactly what I am doing. In the NextJS I am loading stylesheet in _app.js at the top of the file before other imports:
import "react-day-picker/style.css";
...

Stylesheet is loaded and used on local development machine, but when app is deployed to Vercel styles are not loaded.
Any idea why?
